# Rails - Combine js.erb and html.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Right now I have a partial: `_orders.html.erb`and a js view: `orders.js.erb`

The _orders.html.erb code is as follows:

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <div>order.id</div>
<% end %>
```

And the js view uses the above partial to append the partial to an element:

```
$('.profile-content').empty().append("<%= j render('orders.html.erb') %>")
```

How can I combine these two files so that I have one file e.g. `orders.js.html.erb`? I don't want to have two separate files for 4 lines of code.

In terms of what I am trying to do, I have a method in my controller that handles an AJAX request. The method will always render the `orders.js.erb` file, which in turn renders the `_orders.html.erb` file. I would like to contain the view code in one file, i.e. combine `orders.js.erb` and `_orders.html.erb` so another programmer would only need to look at one file to modify the view code.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this and this is how many applications handle server-side rendering. But, we'd have to know more about your application in order to make an attempt at helping you solve what you're trying to solve. Regarding the filename 'orders.js.html.erb' — I believe Rails would throw a fit unless you explicitly state what file you're trying to render. `orders.abc.erb` would instruct Rails to render that file when responding to an `abc`-type request (in your response block)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The controller action gets called from an AJAX request and will always render orders.js.erb. In terms of the suffixes, don't the suffixes just tell rails which preprocessor to use if applicable? So orders.js.html.erb tells rails to first run the file through the erb preprocessor, then the html preprocessor (because there in no html preprocessor it will just leave it as is), and then the js preprocessor, leaving you with js that appends some html. I also added some more context to my question.

Comment: You're on the right track with your thinking about how it's processed. When you `respond_to { |f| f.js }` Rails will look for `orders.js.erb` and then process that with ERB. Likewise, if you registered a custom MIME of "noodle" and `respond_to { |f| f.noodle }` Rails would look for `orders.noodle.erb`. Per the reasoning for asking this question, it's practically a Rails standard to explicitly render a partial in a `.js.*` file. I think you're trying to over-optimize when you really, really don't need to further complicate things.